# Boto file upload to S3 failing on Windows [errno: 10054]

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I'm trying to upload a file to S3 using boto on a windows 7 machine, but i keep getting an error
`[Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`

My code to interact with S3 looks like this

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.key import Key

conn = S3Connection(Access_Key_ID, Secret_Key)
bucket = conn.lookup(bucket_name)

k = Key(bucket)
k.key = 'akeynameformyfile'
k.set_contents_from_filename(source_path_of_file_to_upload)
```

The upload works fine on the same machine using the AWS CLI with the following command

```
aws s3 cp filename.exe s3://bucketname/ttt
```

The file is about 200MB

My OS is Windows 7, python is running through anaconda with all packages up to date. Boto is version 2.25

This code all runs fine from a CentOS box on the same network. So is this a windows issue?

Any help would be much appreciated
thanks!
c

**Debug Output Below**

> send: 'HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:
>   ACCESS_KEY_ID.test7.s3.amazonaws.com\r\nAccept-Encoding:
>   identity\r\nDate: Wed, 14 May 2014  22:44:31 GMT\r\nContent-Length:
>   0\r\nAuthorization: AWS ACCESS_KEY_ID:SOME_STUFF=\r\nUser-Agent:
>   Boto/2.25. 0 Python/2.7.5 Windows/7\r\n\r\n'
>   reply: 'HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect\r\n'
>   header: x-amz-request-id: 8A3D34FB0E0FD8E4
>   header: x-amz-id-2:
>   PwG9yzOVwxy21LmcpQ0jAaMchG0baCrfEhAU9fstlPUI307Qxth32uNAOVv72B2L
>   header: Location:
>   https://ACCESS_KEY_ID.test7.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/
>   header: Content-Type: application/xml
>   header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   header: Date: Wed, 14 May 2014 22:44:31 GMT
>   header: Server: AmazonS3
>   send: 'HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:
>   ACCESS_KEY_ID.test7.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com\r\nAccept-Encoding:
>   identity\r\nDate: We d, 14 May 2014 22:44:31 GMT\r\nContent-Length:
>   0\r\nAuthorization: AWS ACCESS_KEY_ID:SOME_STUFF=\r\nUser-Ag ent:
>   Boto/2.25.0 Python/2.7.5 Windows/7\r\n\r\n'
>   reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
>   header: x-amz-id-2:
>   erataRIpbOrEwOU72VUAqU9AGJ4/kX5z1/UD7rJQy9laKDgOyTyVKABMab8f6wGN
>   header: x-amz-request-id: 2A7BECC45C9BAE7A
>   header: Date: Wed, 14 May 2014 22:44:33 GMT
>   header: Content-Type: application/xml
>   header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   header: Server: AmazonS3
>   send: 'PUT /akeynameformyfile HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:
>   ACCESS_KEY_ID.test7.s3.amazonaws.com\r\nAccept-Encoding:
>   identity\r\nContent
>   -Length: 242642944\r\nContent-MD5: xYOiNcyFKGY1Y/HsYwHQeg==\r\nExpect: 100-Continue\r\nDate: Wed, 14 May 2014 22:44:33 GMT\r\nUser- Agent:
>   Boto/2.25.0 Python/2.7.5 Windows/7\r\nContent-Type:
>   application/octet-stream\r\nAuthorization: AWS
>   ACCESS_KEY_ID:pWs3KwRv9Q5wDnz4dHD3JwvCy/w=\r\n\r\n'
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                         error                                     Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>    in ()
>
> ```
>  12 k = Key(bucket)                                                                                                            
>  13 k.key = 'akeynameformyfile'
> ```
>
> ---> 14 k.set_contents_from_filename(full_path_of_file_to_upload)
>                                                                                                                                       C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\boto\s3\key.pyc
>   in set_contents_from_filename(sel f, filename, headers, replace, cb,
>   num_cb, policy, md5, reduced_redundancy, encrypt_key)
>   1313                                                num_cb, policy,
>   md5,                                                            1314
>   reduced_redundancy,
>
> -> 1315                                                encrypt_key=encrypt_key)
>   1316
>   1317     def set_contents_from_string(self, string_data, headers=None,
>   replace=True,
>                                                                                                                                       C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\boto\s3\key.pyc
>   in set_contents_from_file(self, f p, headers, replace, cb, num_cb,
>   policy, md5, reduced_redundancy, query_args, encrypt_key, size,
>   rewind)                               1244
>   self.send_file(fp, headers=headers, cb=cb, num_cb=num_cb,
>   1245                            query_args=query_args,
>
> -> 1246                            chunked_transfer=chunked_transfer, size=size)                                                       1247
>
> ## return number of bytes written.                                                                                  1248             return self.size
>
> ```
>                                                                                                                                 C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\boto\s3\key.pyc
> ```
>
> in send_file(self, fp, headers, c b, num_cb, query_args,
>   chunked_transfer, size)
>
> ```
> 723         self._send_file_internal(fp, headers=headers, cb=cb, num_cb=num_cb,                                                
> 724                                  query_args=query_args,
> ```
>
> --> 725                                  chunked_transfer=chunked_transfer, size=size)
>
> ```
> 726                                                                                                                            
> 727     def _send_file_internal(self, fp, headers=None, cb=None, num_cb=10,                                                    
>                                                                                                                                 C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\boto\s3\key.pyc
> ```
>
> in _send_file_internal(self, fp,  headers, cb, num_cb, query_args,
>   chunked_transfer, size, hash_algs)
>
> ```
> 912             headers,                                                                                                       
> 913             sender=sender,
> ```
>
> --> 914             query_args=query_args
>       915         )
>       916         self.handle_version_headers(resp, force=True)
>                                                                                                                                       C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\boto\s3\connection.pyc
>   in make_request(self, meth od, bucket, key, headers, data, query_args,
>   sender, override_num_retries, retry_handler)
>
> ```
> 631             data, host, auth_path, sender,                                                                                 
> 632             override_num_retries=override_num_retries,
> ```
>
> --> 633             retry_handler=retry_handler
>       634         )
>                                                                                                                                       C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\boto\connection.pyc
>   in make_request(self, method,  path, headers, data, host, auth_path,
>   sender, override_num_retries, params, retry_handler)
>   1028                                                     params,
>   headers, data, host)
>   1029         return self._mexe(http_request, sender,
>   override_num_retries,
>
> -> 1030                           retry_handler=retry_handler)                                                                         1031
>   1032     def close(self):
>
> ```
>                                                                                                                                 C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\boto\connection.pyc
> ```
>
> in _mexe(self, request, sende r, override_num_retries, retry_handler)
>
> ```
> 905                 if callable(sender):                                                                                       
> 906                     response = sender(connection, request.method, request.path,
> ```
>
> --> 907                                       request.body, request.headers)
>
> ```
> 908                 else:                                                                                                      
> 909                     connection.request(request.method, request.path,                                                       
>                                                                                                                                 C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\boto\s3\key.pyc
> ```
>
> in sender(http_conn, method, path , data, headers)
>
> ```
> 813                     http_conn.send('\r\n')                                                                                 
> 814                 else:
> ```
>
> --> 815                     http_conn.send(chunk)
>       816                 for alg in digesters:
>       817                     digesters[alg].update(chunk)
>                                                                                                                                       C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\httplib.pyc in
>   send(self, data)
>       803                 datablock = data.read(blocksize)
>       804         else:
>   --> 805             self.sock.sendall(data)
>       806
>       807     def _output(self, s):
>                                                                                                                                       C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\ssl.pyc in
>   sendall(self, data, flags)
>       227             count = 0
>       228             while (count < amount):
>   --> 229                 v = self.send(data[count:])
>       230                 count += v
>       231             return amount
>                                                                                                                                       C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\ssl.pyc in
>   send(self, data, flags)
>       196             while True:
>       197                 try:
>   --> 198                     v = self._sslobj.write(data)
>       199                 except SSLError, x:
>       200                     if x.args[0] == SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
>                                                                                                                                       error: [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
>   remote host

Comment: Edited the original post to include the debug output. sorry about the length

Comment: I notice that you are initially getting a 307 redirect.  This is probably because the bucket is in the ``ap-southeast-2`` region but you are connecting to the universal S3 endpoint.  That should all work but just for kicks, you might want to try connecting directly to the ``ap-southeast-2`` S3 endpoint and see if you have the same problem.

Comment: @garnaat You are genius! thanks. i have no idea why that should/would/does fix the problem, but it does. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@garnaat made a suggestion in the comments above that solved this for me. Thanks!! 
For some reason, connecting to the universal endpoint and then trying to upload specifically to the `ap-southeast-2` S3 endpoint fails. But if we use the `connect_to_region` function to initiate the connection and specify the endpoint we want, everything works a-ok! Thanks again, and working example below.

```
from boto.s3 import connect_to_region
from boto.s3.connection import Location
from boto.s3.key import Key

conn = connect_to_region(Location.APSoutheast2,
                         aws_access_key_id=conf.Access_Key_ID,
                         aws_secret_access_key=conf.Secret_Key)
bucket = conn.lookup(bucket_name) # bucket is located in Location.APSoutheast2

k = Key(bucket)
k.key = 'akeynameformyfile'
k.set_contents_from_filename(source_path_of_file_to_upload)
```

Comment: I've been having the same problem, also with a bucket in the ap-southeast-2 region. Weird because I can connect to the bucket and list files without issue but when attempting to upload I get the error you mention above. This also only occurs when connecting from outside the region (ie. connecting via the universal S3 endpoint from within the region then uploading works fine).

Comment: I've been trying to connect with connect_s3().  For small files i had no problem doing set_contents_from_filename() .  But with files a bit larger (~ 300KB) i got this error.  Now everything works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

set_contents_from_filename accepts a string as the source for the file on S3. You are trying to upload an existing file. Try  set_contents_from_file to specify an existing file to upload. Otherwise, read the contents of the file as pass in to set_contents_from_filename as a string.

Comment: I think you might be confusing the method `set_contents_from_filename` with `set_contents_from_string`. `set_contents_from_filename` expects the name of the file to be uploaded as a parameter. See [link](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html)

Answer (score 0):

All of the above answers provide technical solutions but my first experience with this suggested that it was an  *environmental* issue.

I have basically the same code as the original question.  I had no problems the first time I ran it, and then ran into the same error message last night.  I found this answer and many others but decided that since it (my code) worked well the first time (more than 20K files uploaded) I was probably having problems either on my machine or AWS was the source (and/or possibly some point in between).

I shutdown my computer, went home and when I restarted the this morning the original code worked fine.

One of the observations that led me to this conclusion is that while I was searching for the answer I noticed that many posts about the problem all seemed to be occurring at about the same time.  This got me to thinking that maybe AWS was having problems.  Again, I can't be sure if it was my computer, the AWS server or some traffic point - in-between but the original code ran fine when I went after it again this morning.

Here is the code I am using right now ( as you can see very similar to code in original question)

```
import boto
import glob
AWS_KEY = "mykey"
AWS_SECRET = "mySecret"
bucket_name = "myBucket"
numbers = [x for x in range(0,20000,500)]
to_upload = glob.glob('E:\MTurkTablesSelected\\*.htm')

s3 = boto.connect_s3(aws_access_key_id = AWS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key = AWS_SECRET)
bucket = s3.get_bucket(bucket_name)
for n, file_path in enumerate(to_upload):
    upload_key = file_path.split('\\')[-1]
    key = bucket.new_key(upload_key)
    key.set_contents_from_filename(file_path)
    key.set_acl('public-read')
    if n in numbers:
        print n
```

I am now more than 10,000 files into a large upload and not having any problems.