# django and s3 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host on uploading file

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto, django-storage

I am getting an error while uploading an Image in amazon s3:

> error at /
>
> [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

I have already installed django-storage and boto. I saw this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645261/boto-file-upload-to-s3-failing-on-windows-errno-10054), but I think my code and his are very different.

models:

```
def get_upload_file_name(instance, filename):
    return "uploaded_files/%s_%s" %(str(time()).replace('.','_'), filename)

class Image(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, auto_now=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pub_date']
```

In the settings I have added these as it is shown in the [django-storage](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html):

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'REDACTED'

AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'REDACTED'

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'yesme'
```

Will you please help me solve this. Thank you.

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: @doniyor Yes. It was my fault actually. There was no bucket with the bucket name I gave in the settings. haha. If you're having the same problem please check whether you have created the bucket in aws s3 with bucket name given in the `settings.py`.

Comment: Haha good to know, thanks man

Comment: @Kakar I have made an edit to you post to redact the keys, I hope that you have rotated your keys from now.

Comment: @hdost Thank you so much!